# Monitoring specific js events and the time it takes to execute them as part of automated testing?

Tags: javascript, performance, testing, selenium, automated-tests

I am trying to find a reliable way of testing a webapp in order to obtain certain performance metrics. The webapp uses mostly Javascript for its various actions/requests etc.

What I want to be able to do is measure the time between two particular events, for example the amount of time it takes for something to appear to a user after I login to the site - currently I can approximate this using Selenium Webdriver as follows:

```
WebElement element4 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login"));
element4.click();

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
WebElement element5 = wait3.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("New")));

long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
long time = finish - start;
System.out.println("Time taken for New element to load: " + time + "ms");
```

Or using:

```
WebElement element6 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("New"));
```

in place of

```
wait3.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("New")));
```

However the results this will give are not often accurate. What I am wondering is if there is a way to do this more accurately using Selenium, or if there is another tool I can use to reliably obtain this data in a manageable format?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How much accuracy do you need? There will always be an error margin, you have to define what is the acceptable margin for your scenario.

In this case there might be a small overhead e.g. due to Selenium itself (especially if you are running a remote WebDriver). I will assume there could be other random external factors influencing it as well.

That said, you could improve accuracy by running a "calibration" test that would help you to determine the error margin inherent to your own test environment / setup.

Your calibration could go like:

1. Open the page being tested
2. Wait until everything is loaded
3. Measure how long `wait.until()` takes for elements which you know already exist
4. Repeat (3) multiple times to get some statistical significance

At the end you have a list of measurements. Get e.g. the median of it and you have an idea of how much you have to subtract later from the latency you measure when you run your real tests. Or else, you can simply add the error margin and standard deviation as an extra information which you would attach to your performance test results.

Note that in case of Selenium, it will also make a difference which method you use for finding an element on the page (e.g. finding by ID might be faster than finding by "linkText"), so you might want enhance step 3 above to measure the `wait.until()` error for all the different element finding mechanisms.